# Poles of a rationalfunction

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function:

> $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z^{4}+z^{2}+1}$

I want to find the poles. I have deduced that there are 4 simple poles and 2 of them are in the upper half-plane. I'm not sure how I can find them, I have tried to find the zeros of $z^{4}+z^{2}+1$, but with no luck. I have also tried to see if I can factorize $z^{4}+z^{2}+1$, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: First find the zeros of $z^2 + z + 1$..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a quadratic in $z^2$. Write $x=z^2$ to get
$$x^2 + x + 1$$
from the quadratic formula, you get the roots as
$$x = \frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Now find the square roots for each to recover the four roots of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
z^4+z^2+1 &= (z^2-z+1)(z^2+z+1) \\
          &= ((z-1/2)^2+3/4)((z+1/2)^2+3/4) \\
          &= (z-1/2+\sqrt{3}i/2)(z-1/2-\sqrt{3}i/2)(z+1/2+\sqrt{3}i/2)(z+1/2-\sqrt{3}i/2) \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the zeroes of $p(z) = z^4 + z^2 + 1$. Letting $\zeta = z^2$, we must first solve $\zeta^2 + \zeta  + 1 = 0$, which gives
\[ \zeta_{1,2} = -\frac 12 \pm \sqrt{\frac 14 - 1} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt 3i}2 \]
so the four roots of $p$ are the square roots of $\zeta_{1,2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A way to find the factorization is:

$z^4+z^2+1=(z^4+2z^2+1)-z^2 = (z^2+1)^2-(z)^2= (z^2+1-z)(z^2+1+z)$

Then, you can just apply the quadratic formula for each factor.